# Создать jar без точки входа

Tags: jar, java, intellij-idea

Есть некоторые классы с которых хотелось бы собрать (так званую) библиотеку (в jar).
Как собрать такой проект в intellij idea 13?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А в чем собственно проблема? Создаете новый проект, убираете функцию `public static void main(....)` и в итоге получается jar без точки входа.

Или можете отредактировать manifest файл в jar архиве, убрав `main-class`.